# Checking multiple conditions in a case

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

Suppose I have this (inserting into a BST):

```
mybstInsert k inp@(INode left key right)
    | k < key = myNode (mybstInsert k left) key right
    | k > key = myNode left key (mybstInsert k right)
```

What I want is, in the second condition, I want another check as well (checking if right is empty or not). So I want to break the second condition down into two conditions:

```
| k > key && isEmpty right == True = myNode left key (mybstInsert k right)
| k > key && isEmpty right == False = myNode left key (mybstInsert k right)
```

Assuming I have an isEmpty function that takes a subtree and tells me if it is empty or not.

What would be the recommended way to do this? Is this the correct syntax? (I'm working on a computer that does not have GHCi installed so I cannot check the syntax.

Comment: It is correct. Please, check the syntax yourself on any online programming platform, e.g. ideone.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct syntax, but you can also simplify it a bit.

First, observe that the expression `x == True` is equivalent to just `x`. So you can drop the `== True`.

Second, the `== False` part is not necessary at all. This is because by the time you get around to checking that case, it is already known that `isEmpty right == False`, because if it wasn't, you would have stopped on the previous case.

So, the whole thing can be written like this:

```
mybstInsert k inp@(INode left key right)
    | k < key = myNode (mybstInsert k left) key right
    | k > key && isEmpty right = myNode left key (mybstInsert k right)
    | k > key = myNode left key (mybstInsert k right)
```

Finally, I'd like to point out that you're not handling the case of `k == key`, so you program would crash on such input. If you wanted to include that case (and I'm assuming it would just be a no-op), then you don't have to include even the `k > key` check, because by that time it would already be known that neither `k == key` nor `k < key` is true:

```
mybstInsert k inp@(INode left key right)
    | k == key = inp
    | k < key = myNode (mybstInsert k left) key right
    | isEmpty right = myNode left key (mybstInsert k right)
    | otherwise = myNode left key (mybstInsert k right)
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips. (I left out k == key since that information wasn't required for the answer, but thanks for pointing it out too)